# Decoder une chaine de caractere avec html,javascript,php

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

i try to build a formulaire that contain a text input and a button 
when i push the button 
i want to display some messages in my code below

**Example**

```
if my first character is an A 
i want to display "GROUP1-1"

else if my first character is an B
i want to display "GROUP1-2"

else if my first character is an C
i want to display "GROUP1-3"  

if my second character is an F 
i want to display "GROUP2-1"

else if my my second character is an G
i want to display "GROUP2-2"
```

this is my code  when i push the button 
the program work but always there are this message 
"Notice: Undefined index: t in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\exercice\test1\test1.php on line 18,22,26,30,34"

and the program work

i use Notepad++ 
and easyPHP

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>
exercice 
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
decoder ces caracteres 
<input type = "text" name ="t" size="17"/>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<input type ="submit" name ="decoder" value="Decoder">
</center>
<?php
if($_GET['t'][0]=='A') {
echo "GROUP1-1"; 
}
else 
if($_GET['t'][0]=='B') {
echo "GROUP1-2"; 
}
else 
if($_GET['t'][0]=='C') {
echo "GROUP1-3"; 
}
if($_GET['t'][1]=='F') {
echo "GROUP2-1"; 
}
else 
if($_GET['t'][1]=='G') {
echo "GROUP2-2"; 
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you see the value of t[0] when you click submit? Should your comparison letters A-G be wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Somar
no, nothing happen

Comment: only when i click submit the character that i have enter delete

Comment: Your form action is set to `post` but you're using `$_GET`. Change `$_GET` to `$_POST` - something like `if($_POST['t']=='A')`

Answer (score 1):

Your form action is set to `post` but you're using `$_GET`. Change `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['t']) && $_POST['t']=='A') {
  echo "GROUP1-1"; 
} else if(!empty($_POST['t']) && $_POST['t']=='B') {
  echo "GROUP1-2"; 
} else if(!empty($_POST['t']) && $_POST['t']=='C') {
  echo "GROUP1-3"; 
} else if(!empty($_POST['t']) && $_POST['t']=='F') {
  echo "GROUP2-1"; 
} else if(!empty($_POST['t']) && $_POST['t']=='G') {
  echo "GROUP2-2"; 
}
?>
```

Or a better solution would be to use [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
if(!empty($_POST['t'])) {
  switch($_POST['t']) {
    case 'A':
      echo "GROUP1-1";
      break;
    case 'B':
      echo "GROUP1-2";
      break;
    case 'C':
      echo "GROUP1-3";
      break;
    case 'F':
      echo "GROUP2-1";
      break;
    case 'G':
      echo "GROUP2-2";
      break;
    default:
      echo "Invalid Input";
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you uon-pgregorio
the code work
but always there is messages shown
what's the problem,
"Notice: Undefined index: t in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\exercice\test1\test1.php on line 18,22,26,30,34"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean, You should also do a test to know if the form was submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['t']))
{
   if($_POST['t'][0]=='A')
      echo"GROUP1-1";
}
```

Comment: kulturman 
thanks for your response 
I have make all the change 
but nothing happen

Comment: kulturman 
i have change it to $_POST['t[0]']
$_POST['t[1]'] 
but nothing display

Comment: I am confused, since it's working fine for me. What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: I noticed in my code that as soon as I replace `'post'` with `post['t']` the form act as if the method is set to `'get'`. I'm confused about why it behave like this but that might be the issue.

Comment: @GHASSEN7 your text editor has nothing to do with your problems.

Comment: @ uom-pgregorio i can't do it with notepad++ ?

Comment: @GHASSEN7 What I'm saying is it doesn't matter what you use to code. It won't fix the problem.

Comment: @kulturman `$_POST` isn't an array according to OP's question. There's only one `input` element with the name `t`.

Comment: @ uom-pgregorio what i should do to solve the problem ?

Comment: thank you kulturman the code work but always there is messages shown, what's the problem, 
"Notice: Undefined index: t in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 2.0b1\www\exercice\test1\test1.php on line 18,22,26,30,34"